# CoAP image access

Tags: python-3.x, coap

> > I am a newbie to CoAP. I need to access a image stored in my local server. I use python's aicoap module to send requests. My application works well except for accessing images. Is there any way to access images over CoAP.
> >
> > URL: **coap://localhost:8089/error.png**
> >
> > It returns me a error: **Received Type.ACK from UDP6EndpointAddress [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:8089 with local address, but could not match it to a running exchange.**
> >
> > error.png is located in root directory. Other handlers written in Go are working fine for example: **coap://localhost:8089/stuLogin/** where stuLogin is my Login handler.

Comment: No experience with aicoap but I think you need to support a URI like coap://localhost:8089/error and add a handler for it which can return the image as a response.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you receive indicates that the server is sending the response with a token not matching the request, or from a different IP address and port. This is most likely not related to there being an image involved, but more that the client and the server disagree about how the CoAP protocol works.

To further debug this, you can use Wireshark to watch your network traffic. Only if source and destination IP address and port (found in the IP and UDP headers; server IP may differ in a multicast situation), as well as the token (found in the CoAP headers) of the request and the response match, the client can accept it. If either of those does not match, then the server sent a wrong request. If they do match, please report the issue along with the captured package [at the aiocoap issue tracker](https://github.com/chrysn/aiocoap/issues).